# How to resolve "The Google Maps Android API Street View service has been disabled for this application"?

Tags: java, android, maps, google-street-view

I have the following problem on Android Studio when I tried to open `StreetView`

```
"E/Google Maps Android API: The Google Maps Android API Street View service has been disabled for this application.
 This might be because of an incorrectly configured project, or an invalid API key.
 See the Google API console: https://console.developers.google.com, and information about Obtaining an API key:
 https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup."
```

Google Maps API is enabled in google cloud console and google maps works fine in the app.

What should I do?

Comment: Have you paid for a [subscription](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/pricing/sheet/)?

Comment: No. I am using the free service

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Google Maps Documentation says

> With the pay-as-you-go pricing model, the creation of a Street View panorama is no longer charged as a Mobile Native map load. It is charged as a [Dynamic Street View](https://developers.google.com/maps/billing/gmp-billing?hl=en_US#dynamic-street-view) (see below).

Also read details like

> Street View panoramas and map loads are now charged separately. A dynamic Street View panorama is charged for each instantiation of a panorama object in a Maps JavaScript API, Maps SDK for Android, Maps SDK for iOS application.

And so on...

**I added payment method on console and it's working like a charm.**

Cheers! Happy Coding.

Comment: So that mean that you pay for each panorama  init right ?

Comment: @MichaelA yes payments are high.